# New container gets data from the referenced image.. then why need volume?

Tags: dockerfile, volume, docker-volume, volumes

I want to understand the use case of volumes.
eg: i created a docker image using httpd:alipine as my base image. In this images dockerfile i have line COPY ./ui /usr/local/apache2/htdocs.
Whenever i create a new container using this image the images data i.e ./ui folder is added into the new container. So why do i need a volume instead. Even if i use a volume and have data inside it my new container will need a reference image where i use my custom image. So why do i need a volume in any case when the data will be added by the image itself.

eg: docker build -t myimage

docker create container --name mycontainer -p 8080:80 -v my-vol:/htdocs myimage

This new created container will have all the data of the custom image so what is the point of the volume in any case apart from just being a data staging area. Like this any new container created will always carry the data of the reference image used.

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to copy application runtime data into docker image. Only configuration data should be added in docker images creation process as portability is one of the main concern in docker. Docker Image size will unnecessarily increase by adding application runtime data. [Please follow best practices while creating docker images](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).